# Calculating average with AVG for a list of numbers

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, union

This is probably a newbie question (bear with me) but how can I calculate the average for a list of numbers using SQL and the `AVG` function? I mean, I can add together numbers in SQL 
like:

```
SELECT 2+3+4
```

How can I calculate the average of `2`, `3` and `4` without inserting them to a table first?

I have tried different kinds of variations like:

```
SELECT 2 AS foo UNION 3 AS foo UNION 4 AS foo
  foo
  integer
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

but:

```
SELECT AVG(SELECT 2 AS foo UNION 3 AS foo UNION 4 AS foo)
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"

I just can't seem to find the right syntax. I'm on PostgreSQL at the moment if it matters.

Comment: `SELECT AVG(foo) FROM (SELECT 2 as foo  UNION SELECT 3  UNION SELECT 4)x`

Comment: @Mihai: Unless the task requires to fold duplicate values, `UNION` is incorrect, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution depends on where and in what form the values come from.

### [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

Use the set returning function `unnest()` with an array in the `FROM` clause. That's shortest for long lists, but it's a Postgres specific solution.

```
SELECT avg(n) FROM unnest('{2,3,4}'::int[]) n;
```

Which is short syntax for:

```
SELECT avg(n) FROM unnest('{2,3,4}'::int[]) AS n(n);
```

### [`VALUES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-values.html)

Alternatively, use a `VALUES` expression as subquery. This is standard SQL.

```
SELECT avg(n)
FROM  (VALUES (2),(3),(4)) t(n);
```

### [`UNION ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html)

You can do the same with a much more verbose chain of `SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...`. Also standard SQL.

```
SELECT avg(n)
FROM  (
   SELECT 2 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 4
   ) t(n);
```

Use `UNION ALL`, not just `UNION`, which would fold duplicates (which you did not specify!) and is therefore also considerably more expensive.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3414)

Note that all numeric literals in the example are cast to `integer` automatically (just digits). For other data types you may have to add explicit type casts. `avg()` *returns* [(per documentation)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

> `numeric` for any integer-type argument, `double precision` for a
>   floating-point argument, otherwise the same as the argument data type

Answer (score 1):

For your case, SELECT AVG(foo) FROM (SELECT 2 as foo  UNION SELECT 3  UNION SELECT 4) aliasname

like what Mihai said.

Here is the generic syntax:

SELECT AVG (* | [DISTINCT] ALL | column_name) FROM (table_name)

I would suggest learning the function by using columns that have numeric or integer values to average before you go down your route.   Also remember to use group by if you mix aggregate and non-aggregate columns.